# Unable to create a record because join table requires created_at (HABTM + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration, schema, has-and-belongs-to-many

Googling for this, I see the Rails core team is working on a solution for Rails 4 but that's a ways away.

Both `Users` and `Circles` have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship to the other.

My schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "circles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "circles_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "circle_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "password"
  end
```

But in my code, in my `circles_controller` when I try to do this:

```
  def create
    @circle = Circle.new(params[:circle])
    @circle.users << User.find(session[:user].id)
...
```

I get the following error in my browser:

`SQLite3::ConstraintException: circles_users.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "circles_users" ("circle_id", "user_id") VALUES (11, 5)`

What should I do about `created_at` and `updated_at` being false here?

Comment: For your information: has_and_belongs_to_many is also called "many to many" relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it to work by removing the timestamps from the migration that was used to create the join table.

The right schema should be like this:

```
create_table "circles_users", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "circle_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def new
 @circle = Circle.new
 1.times { @circle.users.build } if @circle.users.nil?
end

def create
  @circle = Circle.new(params[:circle])
  @circle.update_attributes(session[:user]) # this will automatically update location table by using relationship
  @circle.save   
end
```

see [HABTM](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: Build gave me a new error, `undefined method stringify_keys`. I also think it would be helpful to somehow write a migration to make the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields be `null => true`

Answer (score 0):

Just give this a try

```
def create
  @circle = Circle.new(params[:circle])
  @circle.users = [User.find(session[:user].id)]
```

Might not work, I have not tried it locally, sry abt that ^_^

Answer (score -1):

In these datetime fields you should insert current timestamp or change them to nullable fields if you not filling them with data.